# Gdiplus::Image from icon resource?

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am trying to draw an icon with gdi+.  I have it working correctly when loading the icon file directly from disk, but I would like to store the icon in resources if possible.  Is there a straightforward way to do this without losing resolution?

```
    // The image draws and looks exactly how I want it to
    Gdiplus::Image indicator(L"\\Indicator.ico");
    graphics->DrawImage( &indicator, 7, 7 );

    // The image draws, but looks bloated and pixel-y
    const HICON hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon( IDI_INDICATOR );
    if ( hIcon )
    {
        Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON( hIcon );
        graphics->DrawImage( bitmap, 7, 7 );
    }
```

Comment: You just don't want to use Bitmap::FromHICON(), it does a poor job mapping the icon to an image.  The image will have only 16 colors from a precooked palette.  Just use DrawIcon().

Comment: Thanks for the input.  DrawIcon() looks much better than passing a bitmap into DrawImage().  The image still isn't as precise as DrawImage() on the icon, but the big reason to use Gdiplus is because I also need to rotate the icon to a specified angle.  For that I believe I'll need to call graphics->RotateTransform() before DrawImage().

Comment: Draw it into a bitmap, rotate the bitmap.

Comment: << Draw it into a bitmap >>  What syntax would I use for that?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Get a Graphics object for a new Bitmap from Graphics::FromImage().  Get the HDC you need from Graphics::GetHDC().  ReleaseHDC() after you draw.

Comment: Yes, I was already doing the GetHDC() / ReleaseHDC(), just hadn't included them in the code snips above.  I found another thread with more info on loading the icon into a bitmap - thanks for the help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511853/displaying-icons-stored-as-resources-with-alpha-using-gdiplus-win32-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before with bitmaps. If it works correctly when loading from disk then it's almost certainly because embedding it as a resource is mangling it somehow. Something weird seems to happen when you store "known" image types as resources. In the case of bitmaps I found that it seemed like some of the bitmap header was getting stripped off which meant that I couldn't load it as a resource if I used a 3rd party image library.

The solution I eventually found was to create a new resource type by manually editing the .rc file and save the icon as that instead. So instead of this :

```
IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON                    "res\\Merckx.ico"
```

You'd have something like this :

```
IDR_MAINFRAME           USERICN                 "res\\Merckx.ico"
```

I don't know if loading it as a Gdiplus::Image with the resource ID will then still work. If it doesn't, you'll probably have to load the resource manually using LoadResource() then create the Gdiplus::Image object from a stream. There's a good article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI) about how to do that.

Hope that helps. I know it seems a bit of a strange solution and but it's worth a try.